# How do I debug a 'Not all temporary messages could be stored' value error in django?

Tags: python, django

I have a class based view that calls info() when a form is successfully posted. After reading [the messaging framework document](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/contrib/messages/) and commenting out the info call I'm sure that its the culprit of the 'Not all temporary messages could be stored' error.

I can't figure out what happens after the info call that causes the error in the post title, though.

Comment: You can post your solution as an answer and accept it. It would probably help future users more as they may not notice the answer in part of the question.

Comment: [it is not merely OK to ask and answer your own question, it is explicitly encouraged](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2011/07/its-ok-to-ask-and-answer-your-own-questions/)

Comment: Done. When I first posted the question and eventual answer, I didn't have enough points to post a separate answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out the number of messages stored in the client-side cookie was maxed out. When the server tried to pack additional cookies into the client's cookie, it failed and raised the 'Not all temporary messages could be stored' value error.

I fixed this by making sure messages could be displayed in the browser by adding a

{% block messages %}

to the website's base template.

Comment: I have the same issue and I already have `{% for message in messages %} ..` in my base.html (without block ). can you explain your solution more plz,

Answer (score 2):

So this issue troubled me for a while. So in case you want your messages to be rendered on the browser, this case maybe when you are developing, debugging or want a sequential message log the you can update the django settings.py file

**Change MESSAGE_STORAGE variable to:**

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.fallback.FallbackStorage'
```

this way it will hit the CookieStorage and then fallback to base storage.

**Other alternative can be to store it in session**

```
MESSAGE_STORAGE = 'django.contrib.messages.storage.session.SessionStorage'
```